Why is the sum of a rhombus diagonals maximal when it is a square
so i got a question at school that goes as follows:
Given a rhombus $ABCD$ with side length equal $a\sqrt2$
the diagonals intesect at point $O$
let $x = AO$

write a function $f(x)$ that describes the area of the rhombus
describe the maximal area of the rhombus using $a$
is the claim that a rhombus that its area maximal is a square true?
is the claim that the rhombus area is maximal when the sum of its diagonals is maximal true?

i solved everything and got to the conclusion that 4 is indeed true but those questions are normally things you need to think about and not create another function and find its min / max points
is there a way to explain logically why is a rhombus area is maximal when the sum of his diagonals is maximal?

Is that not just a case that happens to coïncide with your max case? I suppose you are looking for the intuïtion behind the statement, but that in itself is a pretty vague question. A lot of the times, things are maximal or minimal when some sort of symmetry is there or when some other things are minimal/maximal. Drawing some examples out and looking what area you gain or lose in different cases might help.

Let's look at triangle $\triangle AOB$. It is a right angle triangle. The area is $$A_{\triangle AOB}=\frac12 AO\cdot OB$$
We also know that this is a quarter of the area of the rhombus. Now let's write Pythagoras' theorem for the above triangle:
$$AB^2=AO^2+OB^2=AO^2+2AO\cdot OB+OB^2-2AO\cdot OB=(AO+OB)^2-A_{ABCD}$$
Since the difference is a constant, the sum $AO+OB$ is maximum when the area is maximum. Notice that $AO+OB$ is half of $AC+BD$.

in the second step you ment $AO^2+2AOOB + OB^2 - 2AoOB$ insted of $AB^2+2AB⋅OB+OB^2−2AB⋅OB$ right?

Correct. Misspelled. Corrected now
